# Code Works On PC But Not Working On Mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of code that I'm using on a website:

```
<form action="LINK GOES HERE" target="_blank">

    <a href="#"></a>
</form>
<script>
    $('a').click(function () {
        // do something you want ...
        $('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

(I'm not sure what this "//do something you want..." is, it just came with the code.)

But anyways, this code works for PC but when I tested it on mobile, it did not work.

What do I need to add to make it work on mobile?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You should add what error is happening? All you are saying is that it doesn't work

Comment: Jquery doesn't utilize native click on anchor tags [on purpose](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c9935b6d2db9e1be4bed12f7419e98cdca45763e/src/event.js#L515) but I'm guessing since you're not sure what the comment is there for you maybe lack some experience overall and this could be fixed instead with just changing your anchor tag `a` to `button type="submit"` instead, though hard to troubleshoot such a small example.

Comment: oh, my fault.
it's supposed to submit a form, direct me to a page on the same tab, while simultaneously opening another tab going to another destination.
on mobile, it just directs me to the next destination, it's not opening a new tab.

Comment: How would that look like as the full code?